# Using ASP.NET in GitHub Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, git, github-pages

I am trying to create a personal website on GitHub Pages using the ASP.NET Web Forms template from Visual Studio 2013. (I'm trying to learn ASP.NET/C#)

But it looks like GitHub pages only will load a file named "index.html" as the home page.

I made my index.html file redirect to my Default.aspx file, but it just causes my browser to download that file. This is my index.html file currently:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/JoeWebsite/Default.aspx">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
</head>
<body>
If your browser doesn't automatically go there within a few seconds, 
you may want to go to 
<a href="/JoeWebsite/Default.aspx">My Website</a> 
manually.
</body>
</html>
```

The ASP.NET project is in the correct repo in github. The folder for the project is named "JoeWebsite" evident from the code snippet above.

Is it possible to have a ASP.NET website in GitHub? How?

If not, is there an alternative free hosting service that does?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I know Github does not support ASP.NET, but you can use a free Azure account. Take a look at:

http://www.asp.net/hosting

Answer (score 4):

I think now Github can host ASP.NET but the tweak is a little bit tricky and perhaps it's only specific type. I refer the links for you to check about it:

https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages

Comment: Blazor WASM consists of static files, as far as the webserver is concerned. So that should work on any webserver

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849996)