# Github index.html and MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I seem to be running into a problem. I am wanting to upload my website to github but see that one needs to have the main page as index.html. This is an issue as i have created an empty ASP.NET MVC application with views and controllers that have the .cshtml tag.

How can I create an index.html as the main page and then call my other main page which will be a view, this way all I am doing is getting github to look at index.html and then my main page will be displayed? by index.html calling it.

I have tried to use the following as I saw them mentioned in a few other posts but can not seem to get it to work, I know that it did change my URL but still displayed index.html

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

[Here is a picture of my project folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHGND.png)

Thanks for the the future reply's! Sorry if this post is a bit messy it is my first time posting here. TO add i am trying to host on gitHub through username.github.io

Comment: are you trying to upload to github pages you mean? github pages hosts static sites so it wouldn't host an MVC app for you

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to *host* a MVC site on Github?

Comment: I edited the post and yes i am trying to host with github.

Comment: You can't.  They do not host Asp.Net websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Github does not support ASP.NET, but you can use a free Azure account. Take a look at:

http://www.asp.net/hosting

find answer by [S.Spieker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444314/7262120)

kindly have a look on [Deploying from ASP.Net MVC to GitHub Pages using AppVeyor](https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2014/12/deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-github-pages-with-appveyor-part-1.html) if you want to do via AppVeyor