# Publishing Asp.net website. This 404 error shows up. What am I missing?

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, publishing

[Error 404 shows up after Asp.net published on GitHub. How to finish publishing. What am I missing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJliY.jpg)

Comment: There is not enough information here.  What exactly are you publishing? (I'm guessing some flavor or mvc application) Where are you publishing to? (looks like github pages) Any other context about the problem at hand will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444185/using-asp-net-in-github-pages

Comment: I am trying to publish my website made with Asp.net core to GitHub pages (but I published everything through github and have not used GitHub pages website at all).

Answer (score 0):

I personally never deployed directly to Github before. Usually when i get a 404 error, I start by checking if all my database is linked correctly. Since secret json doesnt get pushed up when deploying, make sure you add any info in secret.json into Github.

Secondly, I comment out if logic in Startup.cs, so error shows on deployed side. This will invoke to developer exception page which you can use to diagnose what the problem is.

```
// if (env.IsDevelopment()) <— this one
//    {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); <— have this invoked even on deployed site.
//   }
```

Sorry i am on my phone answering but if its unclear let me know!